Converting German characters (like ä, ß etc) from Mac Roman to UTF (or similar)?
I have a CSV file which I can read in and at all works fine except for the specific German (and possibly other) characters. I've used chardet to determine that the encoding is Mac Roman
import chardet

def detect_encoding(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        rawdata = f.read()
        result = chardet.detect(rawdata)
        return result['encoding']

Now if I print any lines containing special German characters, I get totally different things, like:

‰ instead of ä
ﬂ instead of ß
÷ instead of Ö
¸ instead of ü etc.

import csv

def read_csv_file_line_by_line(file_path, target_name):
    encoding = detect_encoding(file_path)
    print(encoding)
    with open(file_path, mode='r', encoding=encoding) as file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
        counter = -1
        for row in csv_reader:
            print(row)

As it is a huge file and I'm not sure that I can find all the special cases, I would like to use something to convert everything instead of me picking my cases and replacing everything 1 by 1.
What I've tried so far:

row = [field.encode('mac_roman', 'replace').decode('mac_roman') for field in row] -> it doesn't do anything, the "weird" characters stay still weird
row = [field.encode('mac_roman', 'replace').decode('utf-8') for field in row] ->
row = [field.encode('mac_roman').decode('utf-8') for field in row] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 12: invalid continuation byte

I was unsure, whether it is really Mac Roman, so tried iso-8859-1 and iso-8859-15, but all in vain:

row = [field.encode('iso-8859-15').decode('utf-8') for field in row]

decoded_string = original_string.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8') ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2030' in position 5: ordinal not in range(256)

row = [field.encode('iso-8859-15').decode('utf-8') for field in row]

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2030' in position 5: character maps to <undefined> encoding with 'iso-8859-15' codec failed

Just open(…, encoding='mac_roman') when opening the file‽

It would help if you posted a sample of the file as seen in a hex editor, so we can see the actual bytes and what characters it should be. That way we can tell whether you’re just opening the file using the wrong encoding, or whether the file is already corrupted and needs repairing. These would be two very different problems.

@deceze I never opened the file in a hex editor and I don't even have a hex editor ATM, so I can't do that.

And i also opened it essentially with mac_roman by using with open(..., encoding=encoding) after calling detect_encoding

True, but detection isn’t guaranteed to be accurate. It’s just advanced guessing. Again, getting a sample of the actual bytes and what characters you expect there is the only way to really figure out what encoding it actually is.

You can also open the file in binary mode and print the bytes, if you somehow can’t install a hex editor.

So if I do that how can I (who doesn't really have an idea about encodings in binary form) make a better guess than a library specifically written for this?

You can look at charts for each encoding online and identify in which encodings the bytes match the characters you expect. If you can’t do that, at least post the information here so we can.

It is easy to convert it with pure Python.
with open("input.csv", "r", encoding="mac_roman") as inp, \
     open("output.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outp:
    for line in inp:
        outp.write(line)

If you prefer, there are tools like iconv and recode which do this on the command line.
If you need help figuring out the actual encoding, I have a page where you can look up individual character codes at https://tripleee.github.io/8bit but based on the discussion under your own answer, I guess the real encoding was Latin-1 all along. Maybe you used something which was designed to display results in Mac Roman to view the file?
If you need help with producing a hex dump of the file, this is easy to do in Python; see e.g. Pythonic way to hex dump files but here's my quick and dirty attempt.
import sys

def chunk(filehandle):
    "Read filehandle, yield each 16-byte chunk max and its offset"
    offset = 0
    for data in iter(lambda: filehandle.read(16), b""):
        yield data, offset
        offset += 16

with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as handle:
    for data, offset in chunk(handle):
        hex = " ".join("%02x" % c for c in data)
        s = "".join(chr(c) if 32 <= c <= 127 else "." for c in data)
        print("%06x %-47s %s" % (offset, hex, s))


utf-8 didn't work either...

@topkek: not very helpful your comment: we have no idea on what it is not working. Is it maybe just a display problem (you are not reading file as UTF-8?)

Didn't work how, exactly? Do you get incorrect results or an error?

I fixed a silly indentation error in the code, in case that threw you off.

The SOLUTION:
row = [field.encode('mac_roman').decode('latin-1') for field in row]
Mac Roman to Latin-1

That's strange. To decode something from 'mac_roman' and encode it in 'latin-1' it should be field.decode('mac_roman').encode('latin-1').

It works though.

Are you still using chardet?  Just open with latin1 to begin with. Chardet is wrong

I concur. You open the file using MacRoman and get garbage. You encode that garbage to MacRoman bytes, giving you the original bytes that were in the file. Then you decode those as Latin1 and you get the correct result. = Your file actually is Latin1 encoded.

Latin-1 has the attractive property that it will accept any random byte sequence without errors, but of course, if the encoding wasn't really Latin-1 in the first place, you end up with mojibake

In reality it's very hard to detect extended-ascii (every latin-n encoding as well as macroman) as every byte is valid (technically not the case but practically windows-1252 extends latin-1 with a bunch of mappings for bytes 8x and 9x and they're generally considered equivalent even if not strictly true), I assume chardet has some sort of statistical model to try and guess, and the statistical model for macroman happens to be the closest match for this specific file, because it's a CSV rather than an actual text file.
